# positioning <div> to create layout

Tags: css

So the HTML is divided using divs obviously

```
...
<div id="left">
content
</div>
<div id="right">
content
</div>    
<div id="main">
content
</div>
...
```

I would like to create a layout using CSS that gives us three columns.

```
|      |            |      |
|      |            |      |
| left |    main    |right |
|      |            |      |
|      |            |      |
```

The trick is that I would like the **main** part to be centred and 60% of width.
Left and right to be 20% width.

There will be no images just plain text.

Comment: I just found a way to do this quite simply by using `margin:auto` for main and `left:0` for left div and `right:0` for right div. Also specified widths in %.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tutorials out there fore creating three column layouts, either fixed widths or flexible, fluid columns like you've asked for.

This is a good tutorial with a range of different layouts that should help you get started.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths

Comment: If you read their comments you can see they answered their own question